# Rails: combine two queries into one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-models

I am new to rails. Here is the following code with Foo as model object:

```
a = Foo
a = Foo.where(age: 18)
if params[:sort] == "desc"
  a = a.order("name desc") 
end
```

Here two queries are performed, I want to combine them to one or you can say i want to perform  `Foo.where(age=18).order("name asc")`

Remember there can be the case when order is no needed i.e. params[:sort] is not equal to desc.

Please don't give solution like

```
if params[:sort] == "desc"
    a = a.where(age=18).order("name desc") 
else
    a = a.where(age=18)
end
```

as it makes code redundant and also for more parameters it might not work.

Comment: side note: IMHO re-using name variables is not a good programming practice. Create new variables with meaningful names as you go along, it's much easier to follow the function (and debug it).

Comment: @tokland will try to follow that in future.

Comment: Also, what's up with `where(age=18)`? Shouldn't it be `where(age: 18)` or `where("age=18")`?

Comment: sorry new to rails :), i typed here wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you're mistaken. Actually, no queries are performed here.

```
a = Foo
a = Foo.where(age=18)
if params[:sort] == "desc"
  a = a.order("name desc") 
end
```

The actual query is sent where you start retrieving data. That is, do something like

```
a.each do |b|
  # do something with b
end
```

Until then you can safely chain criteria building methods (`where`, `order`, `select` and others).

Comment: may be you are right but when i look at console it shows me two queries.

Comment: Maybe you do something else. Can you double check that?

Comment: Hey i think you are right, its me only who got mistaken, rather than controller i should look for problem in views. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code will only execute one query. this is because in rails the calls to the database are only done once you access the result. So when you will write a.first (or something similar) it will make the DB call.

Answer (score 0):

If its that what you mean... A simple solution would be:

```
a.where(age: 18).order("name #{params[:sort] || 'asc'}")
```

So if `params[:sort]` is `nil` it will default to `asc`.